# Life Cycle of React

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I am really confused right now as to which function is called first when a MVC view is loaded which has react jsx reference.

I mean I have created an MVC project which loads the view on a click event from another. My other view loads the information and renders in jsx. But this isn't happening. Below is my react code:

**react.jsx**

```
var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        var state = {
            counter: 0,
            initialInfo: []
        };
        return state;
    },

    componentWillMount: function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + '/' + 'api' + '/' + 'Application' + '/' + 'GetUserInfo',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                'userId': '15115',
                'IsUserOffShore': 'N'
            }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                JSON.parse(data)
                this.setState({
                    initialInfo: JSON.parse(data)
                });
            }.bind(this),
            error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
            }.bind(this)
        });
    },

    render: function() {
        return ( 
            <div>
                <AssignValue valueMapper = {
                    this.state.initialInfo.Assignment
                } /> 
            </div>
        );
    }
});

function AssignValue(props) {
    if (props.valueMapper != undefined) {
        props.map((type) => {
            if (type.Type == 1) {
                return <UserGreeting valuemapper2 = {
                    type
                }
                />
            }
        })
    }
}

function UserGreeting(props) {
    return ( 
        <h1> Hello World </h1>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render( <App /> , document.getElementById('authorId'));
```

My above react jsx file is referenced in my index.chtml view which gets loaded from another page click. However, i am not able to understand the life cycle of react. I have gone through this link :http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/

But my react is not behaving properly. it is always calling the **render** function first and then the **componentWillMount** function. due to which my code is failing and sometimes I am getting the error as **A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.**
and 
**attempted to update component `AssignValue` that has already been unmounted (or failed to mount).**

The **this.state.initialInfo.Assignment** value is an array type. Sometimes it is displaying undefined and sometimes it has values which is causing the problem. What am i doing wrong.

Please forgive me as I am a newbee in react.

Answer (score 0):

This function isn't actually *returning* anything (well, technically it's returning `undefined`), which is what's causing your error:

```
function AssignValue(props) {
    if (props.valueMapper != undefined) {
        props.map((type) => {
            if (type.Type == 1) {
                return <UserGreeting valuemapper2 = {
                    type
                }
                />
            }
        })
    }
}
```

It might help if you destructure the code a bit to see what's happening:

```
function _mapper(type) {
  if (type.Type == 1) {
    return <UserGreeting valueMapper2={type} />;
  }
  // return undefined; is implied here
}

function AssignValue(props) {
    if (props.valueMapper != undefined) {
        props.map(_mapper); // Not actually returning the results of .map()
    }
    // return undefined; is implied here as well
}
```

To be honest, it's a bit hard to tell what you're intending to do here. But the fact that you're not returning anything from your function is definitely causing that error message.